# Understanding how closure works in python

Tags: python, closures

Can someone please help me understand how the below code works?
The intent of this code is to take in two elements, make them a pair, Function car returns the first element and Function cdr returns the last element.

I am having trouble with understanding how exactly closure works. I understand how lambda works but still having trouble with the following:

1. the step-by-step flow of this code
2. why pair(f) only takes one input where it's intended to take in 2 elements and make them into a pair
3. what f(a,b) means (why is f in front of the parentheses?)

Thank you so much in advance!

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

def car(pair):
    return(pair(lambda a,b: a))

def cdr(pair):
    return(pair(lambda a,b: b))



p = cons("a","b")
print(car(p))
```

Comment: `cons` is a function that takes two values and returns a function. That function takes one parameter. That parameter is supposed to be a function (`f`), which it will call and pass it two parameters (the ones that `cons` took).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
p = cons("a","b")
```

because in `cons`, it returns `pair`, it is functionally equivalent to

```
def p(f):
    return f("a", "b")
```

then,

```
print(car(p))
```

Which evolve into

```
print(p(lambda a,b: a))
```

and that becomes

```
print((lambda a,b: a)("a", "b"))
```

and becomes

```
print("a")
```